# Count on 2 Columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a count of rows within two columns from different tables located in two different databases.  Something along the lines:

```
    SELECT i.Id, i.Form, h.Form, COUNT(*) AS number
    FROM database1.table1 i

            inner join database2.table2 h
            ON h.table2 = i.table1

        GROUP BY i.Id, i.Form, h.Form
        HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Basically I need to compare the two columns for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you need to join the tables on an id, as what you have essentially written here is

```
    ON table2.table2 = table1.table1
```

so instead of:

```
    ON h.table2 = i.table1
```

you want something like:

```
    ON h.id = i.id
```

assuming that the id's relate to the same obect (i.e. person, record etc.).

So to answer your question, you need to write something like:

```
    SELECT i.id, i.Form, h.Form
    FROM database1.table1 i
        INNER JOIN database2.table2 h
        ON h.id = i.id
        AND i.Form = h.Form
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I just realized I used the tablename instead of the column for the join.  The issue I have is that "id" relates to one table.  Looking for a way to return a count on similar values on the column "Form".

Comment: Ideally you would want a common field to join on, would you be able to supply some sample data for both tables and what they are so I have a better idea of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I came up with:

```
SELECT i.Id, i.Form, h.Form
FROM database1.table1 i

        inner join database2.table2 h
        ON h.form = i.form

    GROUP BY i.Id, i.Form, h.Form code
```

Now I just have to add count of rows to the query...thanks again!